# FILESTREAM driver for Windows Server 2003 or XP?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, windows-xp, windows-server-2003, sql-server-2008-express

Does Microsoft FILESTREAM RsFx driver (for MSSQL filestreams) work on Windows Server 2003 or Windows XP if using MSSQL Express? I know of FILESTREAM driver certified for Windows Server 2008, but what about older systems?

Answer (score 0):

Boris, can your web browser get to this location?
[Supported OS and other info](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506.aspx#SSETools_x64)

Comment: There is no info there on FILESTREAM driver. If your point was that SQL Server 2008 doesn't work on XP or 2K3, it does, only R2 is not supported.